# Android Studio Database SQLite Error

Tags: android

i want to build a database system with android studio, so i follow a step on someone blog.

When  i start to save a data that i have inputted from my phone, the data cannot saved to the database.

Here is the log cat when i run my app

`05-27 17:01:26.579 10597-10597/com.example.opec.menuprototype E/SQLiteLog: (1) table MenuTable has no column named menu_name
05-27 17:01:26.594 10597-10597/com.example.opec.menuprototype E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting menu_name=migor menu_id=1st menu_desc=mie menu_price=12000
                                                                                android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table MenuTable has no column named menu_name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO MenuTable(menu_name,menu_id,menu_desc,menu_price) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                                                                                #################################################################
Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
(table MenuTable has no column named menu_name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO MenuTable(menu_name,menu_id,menu_desc,menu_price) VALUES (?,?,?,?))`

Which part of the code you need to look up ? i will get it for you.

Comment: In what class or activity or fragment are you using?

Comment: If you got error then post your logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
Context context = View.getRootView.getContext();
```

With this line

```
Context context = v.getRootView().getContext();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, now the problem has been solved.